# Duplicate an orchard part

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm trying to use Placement.info instead of overwriting a complete content template and i need to have a part (Parts_Title) displayed in the Content zone and in the Header zone.  I was thinking that have two place with that Part in the Placement.info file would do the trick but it seems that the last one wins.

Is there a way to do that?  I'm using Orchard 1.9.1.0

**Edit 2016-03-16 following Alexander's answer:**

There's something i should do wrong; i have a content type designed in the dashboard (no code) named OffreEmploi.  I use Content-OffreEmploi.cshtml as the alternate.  Here is the code:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement.Utilities;
@Display(Model.Header);
@Display(Model.Content);
@Display(Model.LocalZoneName);
```

and here is my placement.info

```
  <Match ContentType="OffreEmploi">    
    <Place Fields_DateTime-DateDebut="Header:2"/>
    <Place Fields_Common_Text-Duree="Header:3"/>
    <Place Fields_Common_Text-Localisation="Header:4"/>
    <Place Fields_Boolean-Temporaire="Header:5"/>
    <Place Fields_DateTime-DateExpiration="Header:6"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>    
    <Place Fields_Common_Text-TexteIntroduction="Content:1"/>        
    <Place Parts_Title="Header:1" />
    <Place Parts_Common_Body="Content:3" />
    <Place Parts_Title="LocalZoneName:1" />
  </Match>
```

the part Parts_Title is rendered only at the end (in the LocalZoneName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement.info allows you to specify a *single* place to put your part in. This is the reason behind the behavior you see - the last entry wins (`LocalZoneName:1`). And this is where your part's content now resides in - the `LocalZoneName`.

What Alexander was actually suggesting, and what's the usual solution to this (not unusual) scenario is to use a separate, unique zone to put your part in, and render that zone *multiple times*, ie.:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement.Utilities;
@Display(Model.LocalZoneName);
@Display(Model.Header);

@Display(Model.LocalZoneName);
@Display(Model.Content);
```

This will make your `LocalZoneName` (which now containes the Title part) to be rendered twice - before the `Header` and `Content` zones.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this by using only placement.info. The best way for displaying content part twice is to use special local zone for that content part:

1. Create alternate for Content. Display a zone twice in it alternate by using `@Display(Model.LocalZoneName)`
2. Use that local zone in placement.info to render your part inside it `Parts_Title="LocalZoneName:1"`